# plural noun - followed by respectively

Tags: grammar

If one student received A, another B, and the other C, 
Can I use the following expression?

The students received A, B and C, respectively.

Comment: The sentence can mean A student received A,B, and C, B student received A,B, and C, C student received A,B, and C. You have to write "Each of 3 students received one of A,B, and C respectively".

Comment: There should be a comma between _B_ and _and_. Otherwise, OK.

Answer (score 0):

No.  In contexts like this, "respectively" can usually be taken to mean "in that order".  You could say, for example:

> Tom, Dick, and Harry received an A, a B, and a C, respectively.

That means that Tom received an A, Dick received a B, and Harry received a C.

Comment: I don't entirely agree. It would be okay if the previous context had specified the people involved. I think that is implied (although not clear) from the question.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Not clear indeed. if you edited the question to imply that you had already specified an order of students, I think the answer would be different.

Answer (score 0):

The expression, by itself, is fine.

But you **must** identify who the people receiving the things are before you use the expression, or else it won't be clear on who gets what.